# Variadic macros didn't work

Tags: c, macros, variadic-macros

What I want to do is access code with macros. But the complier gives me this error

> identifier "BUTTON___button" is undefined

```
#define BUTTON_1                HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_8)
#define BUTTON_2                HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_9)
#define BUTTON_3                HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_4)
#define BUTTON_4                HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_5)
#define BUTTON_5                HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_13)
#define BUTTON_6                HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_14)
#define BUTTON_7                HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_12)
#define BUTTON_8                HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_11)
#define BUTTON_9                HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_15)
#define BUTTON_10               HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_0)
#define BUTTON_11               HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_10)
#define BUTTON_12               HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_15)
#define BUTTON_13               HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_1)
#define BUTTON_14               HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_2)
#define BUTTON_15               HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_11)
#define BUTTON_16               HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_2)
#define BUTTON_17               HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_0)
#define BUTTON_18               HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_1)
#define BUTTON_19               HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_5)
#define BUTTON_20               HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_4)

#define BUTTON(...)             BUTTON_##__VA_ARGS__


for(uint8_t _button = 1; _button < 21; _button++)
    BUTTON(__button) //=> This should give me BUTTON(1) , BUTTON(2) ... each iteration.But not working
```

By using variadic macros, can I get what I want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must remember that preprocessor things happen before the code is compiled, and is strictly text-only replacement.

Thus, depending on a variable that has different values because of a run-time loop makes no sense, and doesn't work.

The proper way to do this is to put the port addresses (`GPIOA` etc) in an array, together with the corresponding pin for each port:

```
static const struct {
  const GPIO_TypeDef *port;
  uint32_t            pin;
} buttons[] = {
  { GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_8 },
  { GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_9 },
  ...
};
```

then iterate over the data in the array:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof buttons / sizeof *buttons; ++i)
{
  if (HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(buttons[i].port, buttons[i].pin))
  {
     ...
  }
}
```

Comment: any suggestion to get each #define within for-loop.Is there a way to create an array with #define

Comment: No, there is no way. See my answer

Comment: You're starting to [sound very XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), why is the macro the interesting part of this?

Answer (score 2):

The [preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) works at compile-time, and is involved very early (read about [translation phases](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/translation_phases)). So you can't generate macros with a `for` loop. Read [documentation of `cpp`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/) and later your C standard (e.g. [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)).

You could generate your C code with a *different* program -maybe some other preprocessor like [GPP](https://logological.org/gpp) or [m4](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/m4.html), or some script (or your own  other program), and generating C files is a common practice since the previous century (for examples, look into [yacc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yacc) or [rpcgen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RPCGEN), but you'll find many others). You then want to configure your [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool (perhaps [`make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) or [`ninja`](http://ninja-build.org/)) to invoke such a C code generator appropriately.

You can obtain the preprocessed form, e.g. with `gcc -C -E` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). So you can understand what the compiler (its translation phases *after* preprocessing) is getting.

> By using variadic macros, can I get what I want?

No you can't. Read [documentation of variadic macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html).

Answer (score 1):

Variadic macros won't solve anything here. You have two options, look-up tables or X macros. Look-up tables are preferable since they are most readable. But in case you need to minimize code repetition, X macros can be useful, although they are a bit hard to read.

Look-up table version:

```
typedef struct // I'm not sure about the exact types used here
{
  volatile uint8_t* port;
  uint8_t pin;
} button_t;

const button_t BUTTON[20] =
{
  {&GPIOB, 8},
  {&GPIOB, 9},
  ...
};


for(uint8_t i = 0; i<20; i++)
{
  HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(BUTTON[i].port, BUTTON[i].pin);
}
```

X macro version:

```
#define BUTTON_LIST         \
  /*button  port  pin */    \
  X(1,      B,     8)       \
  X(2,      B,     9)       \
  X(3,      B,     4)       \
  X(4,      B,     5)       \
  X(5,      C,    13)

...

for(uint8_t button = 0; button<20; button++)
{
  #define X(button, port, pin) HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIO##port, GPIO_PIN_##pin);
    BUTTON_LIST
  #undef X
}
```